# Is there somewhere to report to when an SE site goes down?

Tags: support, status-completed, bug-reports, downtime

I can't currently reach [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), or [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) (but SO and MSO work fine).  Is this the best place to report that, or is "site down" too ephemeral an event to bother reporting?

FYI, it's not just me: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/superuser.com (as of the time of this post of course).

Comment: The actual question should be "is there something to keep yourself busy with when your favorite site from the trilogy is down", which is the one I'm going through right now :-]

Comment: i had this problem with meta yesterday morning. to make it worse, downforeveryoneorjustme.com was down for me, so i couldn't verify if the problem with meta really affected everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

team@stackoverflow.com

Although It's likely that they will know before you did :)

Answer (score 3):

The sites are having maintenance done right now.  There are headers on the sites that say that, when they're reachable.  I agree, though, it'd be nice to have a notification on meta.  Of course, that wouldn't do anything for meta when it's down.